# include directive acting strange

Tags: java, jsp

I have 5 JSP pages, lets just call them page1.jsp, page2.jsp etc.. the fifth one is called init.jsp..

In init jsp I have this code:

```
<%
    String currentPage = "page1" //Default value
%>
```

In all the other pages I have included this piece of code:

```
<%@ include file="init.jsp" %>

<%
    currentPage = "page2" //re-sets value to whatever respective page you're on
%>
```

I then compile the code and deploy it to the server... I then get this error:

> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 12 in the jsp file: /init.jsp
>   PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   string:///index_jsp.java:101: currentActiveTab is already defined in _jspService(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)

So what I want to know is... why?? Why am I getting this error, if in all the other pages I don't declare the variable again, I simply reference it and change the value....?

PS - 'currentActiveTab' in the error message is equal to 'currentPage' in my example

Comment: But the error is about `currentActiveTab`, not `currentPage`.

Comment: Please see my 'PS' section in my post, the variable 'currentActiveTab' in the error is equal to 'currentPage' in my example

Comment: not equal as in 'it is equal to'. In my example I just replaced the word currentActiveTab with currentPage..

Comment: Why would you do that? It would be far clearer if you just had the actual code and/or error message instead of making people figure out what you're really doing. As it is it wouldn't compile anyway--I have little confidence that what you're saying is correct. Assuming `init.jsp` isn't included more than once, the (corrected) code works just fine, and there's no reason why it wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are declaring currentActiveTab in your main page where you are including "init.jsp"

What I mean is unless you are declaring it twice as follows

`<%@ include file="init.jsp" %>`

```
     <% String currentPage = "page2"  %>
```

**instead of**

`<%@ include file="init.jsp" %>`

```
     <% currentPage = "page2" %>
```

you should be fine.